unable to have leafs following camera in geo node
I worked all day long on anim style trees, but I'm unable to have leafs planes following camera on the second levels of branch.
Do you have any idea how to do it?

I tried different type of setup without any results.

To clarify the question: do you want the leafs to be aligned in a plane parallel to the camera view (i.e. always facing the camera, the leafs normal being aligned with the camera looking vector) ? Because this vector is not related to the camera location, but to its rotation...

(Using Blender 4.2.3)
Setup for the demonstration
The "Leaf" object is made of a grid and a cylinder visualizing the normal, joined with the origin set at world origin. The instancing object to which the GeometryNodes modifier is attached is the default "Cube" object. In the following views of the GN graph, the frame labeled "Camera view axis" is attaching a light grey cylinder to the "Camera" as reference ; this cylinder is aligned with the camera view axis. A Switch node is used to toggle between the normal "aligned with the camera view axis" and "pointing towards the camera location".
Leaves normal aligned with the camera view axis

Using the "Camera" Rotation property, all instanced leaves are parallel to the view plane defined by the camera.
Leaves normal pointing towards the camera location

Aligning the leaves normal (i.e. their Z axis) with the vector connecting the instancing point Position to the "Camera" Location, instanced leaves are oriented towards the camera, ignoring its orientation.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)
